# Writing multiple text properties to a txt file

Tags: c#

I have 3 text boxes & I'm trying to save all three text properties (the properties are defined by different methods/functions) to a text file, on the same line.

Here's what I got so far:

```
        System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
        objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);

        objWriter.Write("You clocked in on " + startTime.Text && "You clocked out on " + endTime.Text && "You worked for " + duration.Text);
        objWriter.Close();
    }
```

When I open up the text file that was created & written to, I get "You clocked in on 11/05/13 02:08"
What it needs to say is this: 
"You clocked in on 11/05/13 2:08 & you clocked out out on 11/05/13 2:10 & you worked for 00:02:00"

startTime is 11/05/13 2:08, endTime is 11/05/13 2:10, duration is 00:02:00.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the && in there?  Should just use +

Comment: @Andrew I tried that & I got the same line coming up.

Comment: Have you removed both && values and replaced them with +?

Comment: @Andrew I just did. I didn't have enough concatenation. Thanks. ~

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just a misprint, but in your case `&` symbol should go in the string, like:

```
    System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
    objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);

    objWriter.Write("You clocked in on " + startTime.Text + " & You clocked out on " + endTime.Text + " & You worked for " + duration.Text);
    objWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
objWriter.Write(String.Format("You clocked in on {0} & You clocked out on {1} & You worked for{2}"
    startTime.Text,
    endTime.Text,
    duration.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use as follows..

```
using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
  objWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("You clocked in on {0} & You clocked out on {1} & You worked for {2}",startTime.Text,endTime.Text,duration.Text));
}
```